# Chart.js in ReactJS app: no terminal error, but no rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, chart.js

I'm currently trying to render a bar chart in ReactJS using Chart.js

info:

official page - http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

gitHub - https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs

The problem I have is that even though my terminal doesn't give me any errors, my local server doesn't render anything.

Here is my code:

```
var React = require('react');
var BarChart = require('../../node_modules/chart.js/Chart.js');
var styles = require('./Styles.js');

var data={
  labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
  datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
  }]
};
var options={
  scales: {
      yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
              beginAtZero:true
          }
      }]
  }
};

var Graphs = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div id='graphDiv'>
        <BarChart type='bar' data={data} options={options} />
      </div>
      );
    }
  });

module.exports = Graphs;
```

Please bear with me if I made some silly mistakes, it's the first React app I'm coding so I have a lot to learn.

I have multiple questions, though:

1. did I install the library at the right place? - I used npm and it is now located in  the node_modules folder
2. Is the path towards the file written correctly? as the gitHub says it should be something like this:

   var LineChart = require("react-chartjs").Line;
3. Is it ok to place the data and the options as global variables?
4. what's wrong with my code if I don't get any error messages from the terminal ?

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `Barchart` from the wrong module. you need to import it from BarChart

```
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs';
```

Also you need to include chartjs as dependency

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
```

and then use it as

```
render: function() {
    return (
      <div id='graphDiv'>
        <Bar type='bar' data={data} options={options} />
      </div>
      );
    }
  });
```

install `react-chartjs` as

```
npm install -S react-chartjs
```

Also make sure to install and import `chart.js@1.1.1` as a dependency in your project . Install it as

```
npm install -S chart.js@^1.1.1
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for answering ;-)
So I did the importation like you suggested and added the chartjs dependency. I also changed "BarChart" to "Bar" in the render module.

however it still leaves me with a blank window.

A few question regarding the importation though: How can I know from where I need to import stuff? since 'react-chartjs' and 'chartjs' have no pathname - when do I have to use 'libraryname' and when do I have to use './path/name.js' ?

Comment: When you install react-chartjs or any module like npm install -S react-chartjs it goes inside your default node_modules folder and then you need not specify the path , rather use the name directly. It's only when u have a custom component that u need to import, that u use the path

Comment: Also Make sure you have installed react-chartjs and chartjs with correct versions as mentioned in the doc

Comment: Ah ok. maybe that's the problem then I've been through my node_modules folder and I cannot seem to find anything called 'react-chartjs'.
I'll just have to find out where it is supposed to come from.

Comment: is it problematic if i have: <code>npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN test1@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN test1@1.0.0 No repository field.</code>

in my terminal after installation ?

Comment: Nope , it wont cause you any problem with your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132223/discussion-between-nootaku-and-shubham-khatri).

Answer (score 0):

Follow Shubham Khatri's post. Then just change the following:

```
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs';
import Chart from 'chart.js';
```

Into this:

```
var BarChart = require('react-chartjs').Bar;
var Chart = require('chart.js');
```

I don't know why but it works.